# How to convert Python lists into a shell-readable series of strings?

Tags: python, shell, output

I have this shell script (called by the file name `depends`) saved in my `$PATH`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in "$@"
do
  depends=+("nodejs-$i")
done
echo $depends
```

and the input (i.e., `$@`) it is designed to take is in the example format:

```
'flatten' 'once' 'is-file' 'multistream' 'piece-length' 'junk' 'xtend' 'bencode' 'readable-stream' 'run-parallel 'filestream' 'simple-sha1' 'minimist' 'block-stream2'
```

. So I would like to be able to write the dependencies listed in a `package.json` file, contained in the `DEP` list variable of this Python script (which has the file name `npm2.py`):

```
import json
from sys import argv
print(argv[1])
from subprocess import call

with open("/home/fusion809/OBS/home:fusion809:arch_extra/nodejs-" + argv[1] + "/src/package/package.json") as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)
    deps = json_data["dependencies"]
    LEN=len(deps)
    print(LEN)
    i=0
    DEP=list()
    print(DEP)
    for key, value in deps.items():
        print(key)
        DEP.append(key)
        i = i+1
        print(i)
        #call(["cpobsn", key, argv[1]])
    print(DEP)
    call("depends", DEP) # returns errors as DEP is a list!
```

to a new variable, say `DEPS`, so that it can then be used as input for the `depends` shell script. If it helps here is my current `DEP` variable that I would like to convert to the standard output shown previously:

```
['flatten', 'once', 'is-file', 'multistream', 'piece-length', 'junk', 'xtend', 'bencode', 'readable-stream', 'run-parallel', 'filestream', 'simple-sha1', 'minimist', 'block-stream2']
```

Hence I am here to ask how I can convert a Python list into shell-readable space-separated set of strings.

Comment: I think you may be confused in your shell terminology. Your sample code passes `DEP` to `depends` as an argument list, but you keep talking about writing it to standard output. Do you want to a) have `npm2.py` invoke `depends` with arguments? b) have `npm2.py` print `DEP` to standard out? or c) have `npm2py` invoke `depends`, writing `DEP` to `depends`'s standard input?

Comment: Good question, I'll modify the question accordingly. It's option a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) takes its arguments in a single list. Try:

```
call(["depends"] + DEP)
```